# Why should/can politics concern aspects of social life?

Tags: politics, social-epistemology

Why should/can politics concern aspects of social life?

Such as those pertraining to relationships or labour rights. Why can one claim that "there exists a right social life model", which is what the implementation seems to suggest.

It's possible that none of the practiced forms are "wrong" (since wrong would be subjective). Then why is it not possible to practice "all possible social life forms", since there cannot be a right one?

Yet, the political context again suggests that someone wants to claim that there is.

---

Or the make the argument simpler:

P1: Humans have no *fundamental meanings* other than bio-material (e.g. reproduction, eating, pleasure, ...)

=> Claims about non-fundamental meanings (such as, many "cultural claims") cannot be fundamental and thus one cannot non-subjectively "claimitize" social life (other than one's own).

Which suggests that "social life" is a form of "physical life" and that social theories that may be accurate must be physicalist theories. That they must rely on empirical verification, which is not possible in "social", because "social" is not hard. It's not possible to study "real social", because it cannot be consistently "claimitized". And everyone could always "form another view". Thus it seems like it would be impossible to conclude on much of anything else than "hard measurable" in social politics.

Comment: See [Aristotle' Politics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-politics/) : "The modern word ‘political’ derives from the Greek politikos, ‘of, or pertaining to, the *polis*’. (The Greek term polis will be translated here as ‘city-state’.) Aristotle's word for ‘politics’ is *politikê*, which is short for *politikê epistêmê* or ‘political science’." Thus, "political science" is the science of *society*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But does it exist as other than subjective conception?

Comment: As moderate  polirical systems fail, they become increasingly litigious and prescriptive, which.accelerates the decay.

Comment: I think you have discovered Quantum socionomics.

Answer (score 1):

### Because people care

As people have desires and preferences on how they want to live, they also have preferences on what kind of society they want to live in, as that society affects their lives in many ways. Therefore people have all kinds of goals (possibly subjective, possibly different and incompatible) that they want to achieve. Some of these goals concern aspects of social life, and thus politics (which is all about social coordination to decide and achieve such goals) also will concern aspects of social life.

While it's tricky to claim that "there exists a right social life model", it's trivial to claim that *I strongly prefer* social life model A to B, which is a valid claim even without any other argument than my subjective preference. As people can and do so, and want to take action to ensure that their preferences get met, it becomes a political concern.

There are all kinds of social policies that may help achieve some of these goals. For example, one may have a goal that the poor working people in their society should have certain protections from exploitation and a liveable income. This goal can be furthered by some set of labor rights policies, and you can have a scientific study on whether some particular policy achieves that goal, and how large or costly is that impact. One might also have a goal that the heavy industrial production output of the society needs to be maximized e.g. to prepare for a major war, and that can be helped by some *different* labor rights policies, and other policies that affect social life; and again there are objective measures on how and why some policies are preferable to others to achieve that goal. So there's a political concern about labor rights policies as a means to achieve the desired attributes of society.

Furthermore, the goals may be inherently conflicting like the two examples above. Different groups of people often have different, sometimes incompatible goals. And there can be objective study on how decisions can be made to take all these goals into account, or, alternatively, on what are the more effective and less effective ways for one group to ensure that *their* goals get met instead of the goals of some other group. So even if you don't have an explicit goal regarding labor rights policies, there's an important political concern about (for example) labor rights policies as means for gaining power or staying in power, which is required to enact other policies that you may care about.